# prepared statement SELECT gives Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm trying to fetch the database with a prepared statement, but I get a "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object " error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!!

```
$peopleID = $_GET['peopleID'];  
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE peopleID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $peopleID);


$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows >= "1") { 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $firstname = $row ['firstname'];
    $lastname = $row ['lastname'];
}
}
```

Comment: @Júlio Jamil `bind_param` indicated mysqli, not pdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_stmt::execute()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) returns a bool (true/false), <strike>not a [mysqli_result](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)</strike>.
Since php 5.3 you *can* use [mysqli_stmt::get_result](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) to get the mysqli_result from a statement instance.

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE peopleID = ?");
if ( !$stmt ) {
    yourErrorHandler();
}
else if ( !$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['peopleID']) ) {
    yourErrorHandler();
}
else if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
    yourErrorHandler();
}
else {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


    ...
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!!! I knew I had a passage missing in the logic chain!  $result = $stmt->get_result(); is what I was missing!   Is this prepared statement on  msqli objet oriented?

Comment: @ VolkerK Just a last question, could u give me an example of a GOOD error handler for these situations? ---- else if () {die (printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) )} ---- is it a good harror handler? Thanks again!

Comment: That's actually a problem: _THE_ error handler.  No, I think that in general sending the actual error message that way to the client/browser  [is not a good idea](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_Leakage#Accidental_leaking_of_sensitive_information_through_error_messages). And Picard cannot abort the self-destruct of the Enterprise because the page hit counter snipplet let the script die? There's very little to mitigate a die() in a php script ;-) I suggest to try to formulate a question regarding that topic (that is not shot down as being too broad, offtopic, ....).

Comment: thanks, I will post another question about it. I understand the "too many informations" that an error message could display, but right now I'm developing this php just for my internal localhost use; so what is important is that, if there is an error anywhere, the transaction is not sent to the db (everything or nothing) and I get a clear message for me to solve the problem. All right, we really don't want to go offtopic now ;) Thanks again for your help!!